# Is there a way to edit a symbolic link without deleting it first?

Tags: unix, symlink

So I created a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link):

```
ln -s /location/to/link linkname
```

Now I want to change the location that the symlink links to. How do I do that? Is there a way to do it without deleting it first?

Comment: I think you would get better response here: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could create the new link with a different name, then move it to replace the old link.

```
ln -s /location/to/link linkname
```

Later

```
ln -s /location/to/link2 newlink
mv newlink linkname
```

If `newlink` and `linkname` are on the same physical device the `mv` should be atomic.

Comment: @Andrew - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation

Comment: FYI, i'm sure this works on some os but this didn't work for me, the move operation just removed the 'new' link instead of replacing the old one. i still had to rm first.

Comment: @pstanton You mean that `mv newlink linkname` caused the `newlink` file to be deleted, but didn't overwrite the `linkname` file? Did it do this silently? That seems extremely mysterious.

Comment: `mv newlink linkname` will move your `newlink` into `linkname` if they are directories. So this method is not 100% perfect.

Comment: @martinclayton @Urda Perhpas you should use `mv -T` instead of plain `mv` ?

Answer (score 30):

Try `ln -sf new_destination linkname`.

Comment: This is non-atomic, though.  See my answer for details. I'm not clear whether that's the poster's concern or not.

Comment: This also won't work with symlinks pointing to directories. It will just create a new symlink inside the old target directory.

Comment: Use the -n (--no-dereference) switch to solve this.

Comment: It would be better to update the answer (but it may be [too late](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144699/phil) now).

Answer (score 28):

Just change the symlink target:

`# ln -sfT /path/to/new/target linkname`

This is an instant, atomic change.

Comment: what is a `T` option? I don't have in my MacOS

Comment: `-T, --no-target-directory treat LINK_NAME as a normal file always` you can `brew install coreutils` and access the GNU versions with a `g` prefix, like `gln` if you want the GNU versions on macOS.  saves a lot of headache when there are subtle differences like this.

Comment: What is implied here? As root?

Comment: `-n` can also work, and has the benefit of existing both on GNU `ln` and MacOS's `ln`.

Answer (score 17):

If the symlink targets are directories, you need to add the `-T` flag to the `mv` command, otherwise it moves the new symlink in to the target directory of the old symlink.

Example of atomically switching a website to a new version:

Original setup - website is stored in `www1` directory, vhost pointing at `www` symlink:

```
ln -s www1 www
```

Browse to website, see old version.

Put new website files in new `www2` directory.

Set up new symlink to new website:

```
ln -s www_new www2
```

Move `www` symlink to directory of new website:

```
mv -T www_new www
```

Browse to website, see new version immediately.

Comment: So apparently the version of mv on my NAS's microkernel doesn't support the -T argument. Any alternative suggestions for doing this atomically?

Comment: Try creating the symlink with the -f (force) flag. That seems to work. See the answer below:

`ln -sf new_destination linkname`

Answer (score 11):

On [OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X), the man page for *ln* says you can do it like this:

```
ln -shf /location/to/link link name
```

From the man page:

> ```
> The options are as follows:
> ```

```
 -F    If the target file already exists and is a directory, then remove it so that the link may occur.  The -F
       option should be used with either -f or -i options.  If none is specified, -f is implied.  The -F option is
       a no-op unless -s option is specified.

 -h    If the target_file or target_dir is a symbolic link, do not follow it.  This is most useful with the -f
       option, to replace a symlink which may point to a directory.

 -f    If the target file already exists, then unlink it so that the link may occur.  (The -f option overrides any
       previous -i options.)

 -i    Cause ln to write a prompt to standard error if the target file exists.  If the response from the standard
       input begins with the character `y' or `Y', then unlink the target file so that the link may occur.  Other-
       wise, do not attempt the link.  (The -i option overrides any previous -f options.)

 -n    Same as -h, for compatibility with other ln implementations.

 -s    Create a symbolic link.

 -v    Cause ln to be verbose, showing files as they are processed.
```

Comment: What version of OS X? The default shell was [changed to Z shell in macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina#Removed_or_changed_components) (Catalina. 2019-10-07), if it matters.

Answer (score 7):

For directories, you want to do: 
ln -sfT /location/to/new/target old_linkname

Comment: this is a much better solution than having to call a second command

Comment: Isn't this already covered in previous answers?

Answer (score 5):

No.  The `symlink` system call will return `EEXIST` if newpath already exists.  You can only link from a new node in the filesystem.  What's the requirement here?  If you're worried about a race due to the non-atomicity of the unlink/symlink calls, then you might want to rethink the architecture a little to provide synchronization elsewhere.  There have been some scary security bugs introduced by this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, you basically have to delete the symlink first, either manually or by passing the `-f` flag to the `ln` utility.

Years ago, I had to make small edits to symlinks pretty frequently, so I wrote a simple readline-based utility (`edln`) to make this less annoying. In case anyone else finds it useful, I've put it online at https://github.com/jjlin/edln/.

`edln` will display the original symlink target; you can then use the arrow keys, or standard readline keystrokes (`M-b`, `M-f`, `C-d`, etc.) to move around and edit the target.

Comment: thank you! i could compile and run it on [tag:openbsd], the makefile misses install target though :-)

Comment: Just a note that, at least with today's bash, you can use `read` built-in's readline support: `read -e -p 'New: ' -i "$(readlink -- "$1")" lnk`

Comment: It would be quite nice to have a version of edln implemented as a bash script, but readline behavior doesn't appear to be as customizable via bash. I gave it a shot, but I haven't figured out how to avoid undesirable behavior like shell-escaped filename completions.

Comment: `(touch 'a b'; IFS= read -e -p 'New: ' -i ./ lnk; echo ":$lnk:"; ls "$lnk")` seems to work for me, `read -e` undoes the escapes; there's just a trailing whitespace after pressing <TAB> the user must delete

Comment: Ah... the key is *not* passing `-r` to `read` -- with all its implications. Then tab-completion adds escapes, which are undone by `read`'s default behavior

Answer (score 3):

Chain the commands like this:

```
rm currentlink && ln -s /path/to/link currentlink
```

The first command removes the existing one and the 2nd immediately creates it again.

Answer (score 1):

Just googled, found no good answer and had to solve myself:

```
ln -f -s -T `readlink SomeLibrary | sed 's/version.old/version.new/'` SomeLibrary
```

Editing by definition means not recreating from scratch but changing partly. Any answer requiring to memorize a path, maybe long or with weird symbols, is definitely bad.

Comment: What do you mean by "memorize a path"? Why would that be necessary? Can you provide an example of that?